# Is Jquery a replacement for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to coding websites with HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I used W3 schools recently to learn more in depth and have started coding my portfolio. But then noticed jquery tutorials and they didnt mention this.

Comment: jquery is an library for javascript

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Also for being downvoted I'll make sure to properly ask or thoroughly search better next time

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on their own web:

"What is jQuery?
jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers."

Is not a replacement, it's like a bunch of functions already implemented.

I hope this was usefull for you!